# Criar uma condição dentro de um Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Preciso fazer uma comparação para setar o valor dentro do meu `select new`. Vou tentar explicar melhor.

```
      var tipo= from t in p
                   select new
                   {
                       t.Key,
                       t.Value,
                   };

        return Ok(tipo);
```

Queria comprar se t.key == "azul" se fosse, ele setaria somente esse valor. Caso ele fosse outra coisa, setaria o valor referente.
Tentei criar um if() dentro do linq, porém a linguagem n permite. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso comprar?

O valor que quero comprar é com um Enummeration.

Comment: O que é "esse valor" e "valor referente"?

Comment: O nome que está no meu enummeration

Comment: Isso é muito genérico, especifique exatamente o que você precisa pegar. Lembre-se que eu não conheço seu código.

Comment: Quero obter do meu select new somente se valor que vem da minha tela é igual a um valor que está no meu Enummeration

Answer (score 2):

Tua pergunta tá meio confusa, mas creio que seja isso que tu precisas.

```
var tipo = from t in p
           select new
           {
               t.Key == "Azul" ? "ValorSeAzul" : "OutroValor",
               t.Value,
           };    

return Ok(tipo);
```